# AutoComplete with render item to dynamic textbox in razor view?

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have few textbox in razor partial view which will be available based on condition. Out of that 1 is attached to autocomplete with below code but when the partial view is loaded then i get error (if textbox is not available)

> 0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to set property
>   '_renderItem' of undefined or null reference

if the textbox is available in Razor view then error doesn't appear.

My code for Jquery is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    var view = $(document).findByClass("product-view");
    var companysource = view.data("datasource-url");
    $("#txtcompany").autocomplete({
        minLength: 0,
        source: function (request, resonse) {
            $.ajax({
                url: companysource,
                data: { term: $('#txtcompany').val() },
                dataType: "json",
                type: "GET",
                success: function (data) {
                    resonse(data);
                }
            });
        },
        focus: function (event, ui) {
            $("#txtcompany").val(ui.item.Name);
            return false;
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            $("#txtcompany").val(ui.item.Name);
            return false;
        },
        change: function (event, ui) {
            if (ui.item == null) {

            } else {

            }
        }
    })
    .data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
        return $("<li>")
            .data("ui-autocomplete-item", item)
            .append("<div style='margin-bottom:2px; padding:1px 1px; font-size:14px;'><a>" + "<b>Company Name: </b>" + item.Name + "</a></div>")
            .appendTo(ul);
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first check if textbox is present in dom:

```
  var txtcompany = $("#txtcompany");
  alert(txtcompany.length);

  if (txtcompany.length === 1) {

      txtcompany.autocomplete({ ...

  };
```

Comment: Thanks @irfan. I did something like that  .length >1